# How do I 'lfs pull' on a specific submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-lfs

I need to perform an lfs pull for a specific git submodule.

How can I perform a 'git lfs pull' on a specific submodule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Submodules are normal Git repositories, so you can just change into it with `cd` or by using the `-C` option to `git`.  So if your submodule were in `foo/bar`, you'd write the following:

```
$ git -C foo/bar lfs pull
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute a command on all submodule repositories `git submodule foreach <command>` can be used.

`git submodule foreach git lfs pull` is a neat trick on [@bk2204](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8705432/bk2204)'s answer without caring for submodule names/paths.